# Ajax load more button for comments wordpress

Tags: php, functions, jquery, comments, javascript

I have my own Ajax load more button system but for posts now i decide to make the same thing but for comments so after check get_comments i found that i can't get the CURRENT page of comments like posts.

So anyone have any example to help me about this? Because comments is totally different than posts.

- DON'T NEED ANY PLUGINS.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this question is old but still has no answer!

Here is a small solution for future visitors.

Implementing load more button for comments without plugins is simple enough:

1. Create a button if comment pages are 2 and more
2. Create a jQuery script that will process the button click event and passes the current comment page number to `wp_ajax_` action hook
3. The last step – is `wp_ajax_` function that will process the AJAX request.

That's all!

But if you need the ready code, please look at this tutorial https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-comments.html